# train loss and dice coefficient giving nan result

Tags: metrics, training-data, loss, unet-neural-network

i build unet model to segment diabetic retinopathy lesion, but when i did the training with 30 epochs, it give nan value in test loss and dice coefficient

```
startTime = time.time()
batch_size= 2

train_dataset = ProcessDataset(train_x, train_y)
test_dataset = ProcessDataset(test_x, test_y)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, 
num_workers=os.cpu_count(), pin_memory=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, 
num_workers=os.cpu_count(), pin_memory=True)

device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = Build_Unet()
model.to(device)

trainSteps = len(train_dataset) // batch_size
testSteps = len(test_dataset) // batch_size

H = {"train_loss": [], "test_loss": [], "accuracy": [], "dice": []}

criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
criterion.to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

num_epochs = 30

for epoch in range(num_epochs):

    model.train()

    totalTrainLoss = 0
    totalTestLoss = 0

    for i, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):

        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
        target = target.unsqueeze(1) 

        output = model(data)
        loss = criterion(output, target)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        totalTrainLoss += loss

    with torch.no_grad():

        model.eval()

        total_dice = 0

        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            target = target.unsqueeze(1) 

            output = model(data)

            loss = criterion(output, target)
            totalTestLoss += loss

            pred = torch.round(output)

            dice = compute_meandice(pred, target, include_background=False)
            total_dice += dice

    avg_dice = total_dice / len(test_loader)
    avgTrainLoss = totalTrainLoss / trainSteps
    avgTestLoss = totalTestLoss / testSteps

    H["train_loss"].append(avgTrainLoss.cpu().detach().numpy())
    H["test_loss"].append(avgTestLoss.cpu().detach().numpy())
    H["dice"].append(avg_dice)

    print("EPOCH: {}/{}".format(epoch + 1, num_epochs))
    print("Train loss: {:.4f} | Test loss: {:.4f}".format(
           avgTrainLoss, avgTestLoss))
    print("Dice coefficient: {:.4f}".format(avg_dice.mean().item()))

endTime = time.time()
print("[INFO] total time taken to train the model: {:.2f}s".format(
    endTime - startTime))
```

here i want to print training loss, test loss, and dice coefficient to see my model performance, but i got stuck in test loss and dice coeficient giving nan value like this

[image]

since i'm newbie in pytorch, anyone know how to fix it? or is there something strange in my code? thankyou in adanvance!

Comment: Did you try a different numer of epochs? What happens with just 1?

Comment: @Spencer i'm sorry, what do you mean just 1?

Comment: Set `num_epochs = 1` and see the results you get.

Comment: @Spencer here what i got
EPOCH: 1/1
Train loss: 0.6875 | Test loss: nan
Dice coefficient: nan

Comment: OK, so are you running this on your full dataset or a small test dataset?

Comment: @Spencer on 53 images train dataset, and 27 images test dataset